# Width of three columns

Tags: css, width, z-index

I have been sitting for a while to come up with a solution to a problem. I want to make a website that consists of three columns (left, center, right). These three will together cover the entire screen width. One column will consist of a fixed pixel value and the other two columns should be as wide that the middle column is centered on the screen.

The reason I need the left and right columns is because I want to hide things behind them, and then animate these things into the center column.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: I solved the problem, but not by using three columns. Instead I just centered the middle column and used clip to hide everything outside of the specified pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not happy about the width: 10000% bit on this, maybe someone can come up with a cleaner solution but I think this will do what you're describing. These kinds of layouts are a little tricky when you're looking for a pure CSS solution.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<p>Content goes in here</p>
<ul>
    <li>Whatever</li>
    <li>Kind</li>
    <li>Of</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</ul>        
<div class="sideCol" id="left"></div>
<div class="sideCol" id="right"></div>
```

​

CSS:

```
#content
{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.sideCol
{
    width: 10000%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#left
{
    background-color: red;
    right: 200px;
    top: 0;
}

#right
{
    background-color: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fLH9T/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left { float:left; width:33%; height:200px; z-index:100; diplay:block; }
.center { float:left; width:33%; height:200px; z-index:1; diplay:block; }
.right { float:right; width:33%; height:200px; z-index:100; diplay:block; }
```

I assume this is what you want.

Comment: use `32.8%` or `32.7%` instead of `33%`

Comment: Didn't OP want a fixed width middle column?